# how to create pdf file form template in django

Tags: python, django, pdf

I want to make a pdf file using Django. I found the ReportLab and I implemented but the main problem is that I want to create the pdf file from my template. How can do this ?

This is the View

```
 from io import BytesIO
 from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 import random


def write_pdf_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="mypdf.pdf"'

    buffer = BytesIO()
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
    papercustomization = ShortBlankDescriptionQuestions.objects.get(id=1)
# Start writing the PDF here
    p.drawString(100, 100, papercustomization.sbd_question_text)
# End writing

    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    pdf = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()
    response.write(pdf)

    return response
```

Comment: Assuming your template outputs HTML, you may want to ask yourself  "how to generate pdf from html" instead - and then google might come up with some more-or-less working solutions.

Comment: Are you able to produce html with your template? Are you looking for client side or server side conversion?

Answer (score 0):

**# Specific Teacher Reports of a school made in Reportlab with Django2.2 and Python 3.8
**

**# views.py**

```
class docente(View):
    def _header_footer(self,canvas,doc):
        canvas.saveState()
        canvas.setTitle("PDF")
        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        header20 = Paragraph('Fecha: '+ time.strftime("%d/%m/%y"), styles['Normal'])
        w, h = header20.wrap(doc.width-320, doc.topMargin)
        header20.drawOn(canvas, 520, doc.height + doc.topMargin+15 )
        footer = Paragraph('', styles['Normal'])
        w, h = footer.wrap(doc.width, doc.bottomMargin)
        footer.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin, h)
        canvas.restoreState()

    def get(self,request,  pk=None):
        print ("Genero el PDF")
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        pdf_name = "clientes.pdf"  # llamado clientes
        # la linea 26 es por si deseas descargar el pdf a tu computadora
        # response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % pdf_name
        buff = BytesIO()
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buff,
                                pagesize=letter,
                                rightMargin=40,
                                leftMargin=40,
                                topMargin=110,
                                bottomMargin=40,
                                )
        if request.user:
            clientes = []
            styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
            header=Paragraph('Reporte del Docente',styles['Heading1'])
            clientes.append(header)
            allclientes = Docente.objects.filter(pk=pk) 
            header5=Paragraph('',styles['Heading4'])
            clientes.append(header5)
            header5=Paragraph('Lista del docente',styles['Heading4'])
            clientes.append(header5)
            listas = []
            count = 0
            for i in allclientes:
                count = count+1
                vari = (count,i.cedula_docente,i.nombre_docente,i.apellido_docente,i.sexo,i.edad)
                listas.append(vari)

            #TABLA NUMERO 1
            headings1 = ('N°','CEDULA','APELLIDOS','NOMBRES','SEXO','EDAD')
            t1 = Table([headings1] + listas)
            t1.setStyle(TableStyle(
                [   ('GRID', (0, 0), (5, -1), 1, colors.black),
                ('LINEBELOW', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 2, colors.black),
                ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.dodgerblue)
                ]
                ))
            header5=Paragraph('',styles['Heading4'])
            clientes.append(header5)
            clientes.append(t1)

            doc.build(clientes,onFirstPage=self._header_footer,onLaterPages=self._header_footer,canvasmaker=NumberedCanvas)
        else:
            clientes = []
            styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
            header=Paragraph('Lista de usuarios registrados',styles['Heading1'])
            clientes.append(header)
            doc.build(clientes,onFirstPage=self._header_footer,onLaterPages=self._header_footer,canvasmaker=NumberedCanvas)
        response.write(buff.getvalue())
        buff.close()
        return response




class NumberedCanvas(canvas.Canvas):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._saved_page_states = []


    def showPage(self):
        self._saved_page_states.append(dict(self.__dict__))
        self._startPage()


    def save(self):
        """add page info to each page (page x of y)"""
        num_pages = len(self._saved_page_states)
        for state in self._saved_page_states:
            self.__dict__.update(state)
            self.draw_page_number(num_pages)
            canvas.Canvas.showPage(self)
        canvas.Canvas.save(self)


    def draw_page_number(self, page_count):
        self.setFont("Helvetica", 9)
        self.drawRightString(211 * mm, 4 * mm + (0.1 * inch),"Pagina %d de %d" % (self._pageNumber, page_count))
```

**# urls.py**

```
path('docente/<int:pk>',login_required(docente.as_view()), name = 'docente'),
```